# How to make an if statement based on how much time passed?

Tags: c++, time

I'm looking for a way to add an `if` statement that would go as the following, just unsure how to do it.

```
if(120 seconds have passed)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

alt would be (assuming x is the time passed between each check)

```
do
{
    // do stuff
    x = 0;
}while(x=120)
```

So then it would loop constantly.
Could anyone show me a solution to this ?

Comment: Have you looked up how to check how much time has elapsed, or searched for this question at all? I suspect this have been answered dozens of times over.

Comment: yes I have but I don't understand it, some answers are with Chrono, some are with the c++ time library and I don't understand how to use it thus I need to ask this myself @Carcigenicate

Comment: You should narrow this question down, because the question as statedalready has answers elsewhere. If you need help using Chrono, show your attempt to use it, and explain what specifically you don't understand.

Comment: This is the problem, alot of answers that don't answer my question, I don't know how to use Chrono yet however I can narrow it down to this ;

Comment: I would like to change a bool type every 120 seconds but I don't want it to break (aka sleep is not an option)

Comment: This is a near duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735307/c-keeping-track-of-how-many-seconds-has-passed-since-start-of-program

Comment: I see what you mean and just one more question in that same example can I use the variable "seconds_since_start" for an if statement (aka if(seconds_since_start = 120) and could I reset it by writing seconds_since_start = 0?

Comment: Apart of above: while(x=120) will never exit since it assigns 120 into x not checks its value, so is equal to while(120) -> while(true). You want to use x == 120

Comment: @Jungha 1. You'll probably want to check if `seconds_since_start` is *greater* than 120 not equal (`==`) to 120. In the event that your program freezes for a couple seconds at 119 seconds, it may skip over 120 and run forever. 2. You could, yes. That variable is just a double.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Keeping track of how many seconds has passed since start of program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735307/c-keeping-track-of-how-many-seconds-has-passed-since-start-of-program)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Boost.DateTime](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/date_time.html) to do the job.

Here is an example describing each step:

```
const boost::posix_time::ptime start = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
// Do stuff
const boost::posix_time::ptime end = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
const boost::posix_time::time_duration duration = end - start;
const boost::posix_time::time_duration remaining = boost::posix_time::seconds(120) - duration;
boost::this_thread::sleep(remaining);
```

It can be simplified by this way:

```
const boost::posix_time::ptime start = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
// Do stuff
boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(120) - boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time() + start);
```

Or simplified by this way:

```
const boost::posix_time::ptime end = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time() + boost::posix_time::seconds(120);
// Do stuff
boost::this_thread::sleep(end - boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time());
```